# Existence of all stable nonlinear system.

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Consider a nonlinear dynamical system that evolves with a continuously differentiable vector field that is there exists a compact set within which the solution trajectories exist and are unique. Is it possible that all the stationary points of the dynamical system are stable? (Apart from the trivial scenario of having only one steady state.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It turns out that it is NOT possible to have a dynamical system with continuously differentiable dynamics for which all the steady states (<1) are stable.